# Very Specific Filtering in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, calculator

I am making a calculator in Google sheets and I would like to find a formula or script or something that will allow me to read the value of a certain square and add the formula "=sum(C5:C9)" or "=product(C5:C9)" or whichever depending on what the person puts in C4. Not sure if this is possible in google sheets (without custom code), but if it is, that would be great!

Comment: Try ````IF()````

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(C4="*"; PRODUCT(C5:C9); SUM(C5:C9))
```